# How to fix: iMessage Unavailable: Turn on cellular data or use Wi-Fi to set up iMessage

Tags: messages, iphone, ios

My iPhone 5 suddenly ceased using iMessages. The phone is unlocked, has ios 9.3.2 installed, I have very few apps installed, and no new apps installed recently.

When I go to Settings > Messages > iMessage and try to toggle, I get the following:

> **iMessage Unavailable**
>   Turn on cellular data or use Wi-Fi to set up iMessage.

However, cellular data **is** enabled in Settings > Cellular > Cellular Data. Cellular data seems to be working fine in Safari, apps, etc. I get the same behavior with LTE or 4G cellular.

I have tried all of the following based on hunches and information gleaned from non-stackexchange sites:

- Restarting Messages
- Restarting the phone
- Resetting network settings
- Resetting the phone's passcode
- Resetting the AppleID account password associated with this phone
- Erasing all content and settings from the phone, and then restoring from backup
- Ejecting the SIM card, and replacing it.

How to get this basic functionality to work again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so there's at least one solution:

1. **Establish a Wi-Fi connection** using Settings > Wi-Fi (switch on, etc.).
2. **Log-in** the iphone **using AppleID** when prompted.
3. ***Disconnect* cellular** using Settings > Cellular > Cellular Data (switch to OFF).
4. **Switch iMessage on** (Facetime, etc.) in Settings > Messages > iMessage.
5. **Switch cellular data on** by reversing step 3.
6. **Switch Wi-Fi off** if so inclined by reversing step 1.

That did it!

Also? Screw Apple! Talk about cut-rate functionality…